# Merge multiple CSS files together with import

Tags: css, import, merge

I have like 10 CSS files, all of these files are imported into a main.css file, I asked myself if it is possible to like merge all of these imported files together. Now I got a main.css which includes just imports, what I want is a main.css file which includes just CSS from all other files, optionally in different sections with comments that includes the file name. Do you know what I mean and is there any solution?

Comment: You'd have to do that either manually or with a server-side language of your choice.

Comment: You mean what every preprocessor out there is doing? Like SASS, Less, Stylus, PostCSS? https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import

Comment: Can't you copy and paste the content of the css files inside your main.css?

Comment: @laruiss Nearly, I dont want to use SASS for this project and was searching for a CSS only way, not just for the project also for personal interest IF there is any solution. Thanks for the "postcss import" tip, really useful I guess.

Comment: @LucaDeNardi I could, but I wouldve been to do it every time I add changes and this would be kinda useless then, I just searching for a way to kinda merge a CSS file from all the imported other CSS files into one seperate file. To like use it when you want to upload it to your FTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **cat** tool in Linux and Unix-like operating systems.

Say you have for files in your css directory, each handling a specific aspect:

- typography.css
- layouts.css
- colors.css
- forms.css

You can merge them into one file like so:
*cat typography.css layouts.css colors.css forms.css > all.css*

But do remember to order them properly to avoid